# Error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 during trying to send an email

Tags: java, spring, email

I would like to send an email, when someone will try order thing in my application. So I have created a two main method to do this. The first sender method set configurations for sender. There I set host, user data, port, and other settings.

```
@Configuration
public class EmailData {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost("poczta.interia.pl");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);
        javaMailSender.setUsername("myemail@interia.pl");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("adminadmin123");
        Properties properties = javaMailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

And the second method in class service trying to send a message:

```
@Service
@Async
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String toEmail, long idOrder) {

        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("myemail@interia.pl");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo("myemail1@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("subject");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("Thanks for your order!");

        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
}
```

There I am trying to send an email, but last line throws an exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

Also I have a configuration in properties file:

```
spring.mail.host=poczta.interia.pl
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=myemail@interia.pl
spring.mail.password=adminadmin123
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

What is wrong? Why it throws an error? It seems that email and password are correct.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had this exact error but it turned out I just had wrong password

Comment: I had this error, it was solved when I set starttls.enable to true. I expect you are getting it because you have smtp.auth set to false - try it as true.